# ajax api and check if data is newer then previous call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm checking an api for some NFL scores , but the data is not always newer than the previous request I've made.

Site owner has no time to fix the issue. I check the API every 10 seconds and I keep getting old items. The api is only updated when NFL games are live , so you can't actually see the issue until then , but opening the link in your browser and refreshing you see the data is always retrieving old and new .  Is there a easy way to fix this on my end ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.myfantasyleague.com/2022/export?TYPE=nflSchedule&W=&JSON=1',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
            console.log("No Schedule Exists")
        } else {
            // if data is old - do nothing
            // id data is new then proceed
            console.log(data)
        }
        data = null;
    }
});
```

during live games , all the items jump back and fourth from older to current/new

```
{"kickoff":"1663287300","gameSecondsRemaining":"0","team":[{"inRedZone":"0","score":"24","hasPossession":"0","passOffenseRank":"4","rushOffenseRank":"24","passDefenseRank":"19","spread":"3.5","isHome":"0","id":"LAC","rushDefenseRank":"10"},{"inRedZone":"0","score":"27","hasPossession":"0","passOffenseRank":"7","rushOffenseRank":"15","passDefenseRank":"21","spread":"-3.5","isHome":"1","id":"KCC","rushDefenseRank":"13"}
```

Comment: How do you detect that data is "old"?  Is there a timestamp?  Is it the same as previous data?  Is the "kickoff" a timestamp or just a record-id?

Comment: I would need to compare gamesecondsremaing for each matchup , if each matchup has gamesecondsreaming are equal to or more then initial Ajax , then don’t  Ajax again

Comment: I’m assuming I need a array to put in each matchup and gamesecondsremaining in , then compare to new ajax request

Comment: What's "matchup"?  Is there an id?    These terms no doubt make sense to you, but this is the first time we're seeing this.

Comment: Something like: `var games = [];` ... `games[data.kickoff] = games[data.kickoff] || data;  if (data.gameSecondRemaining < games[data.kickoff].gameSecondsRemaining) games[data.kickoff] = data;`  if new data seconds remaining is less than *previous* seconds remaining then it must be new data, so update, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: the api has matchup to determine how many games scheduled , so loop through each

Comment: if you can look at api and give a answer that would be great - https://api.myfantasyleague.com/2022/export?TYPE=nflSchedule&W=&JSON=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are displaying this data, but lets say you have a Div for each game..

When you update the information save the `gameSecondsRemaining` as an attribute in the Div / container

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.myfantasyleague.com/2022/export?TYPE=nflSchedule&W=&JSON=1',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
            console.log("No Schedule Exists")
        } else {

            // if data is old - do nothing
            if ( // if container has attribute && attr is newer
                $("#game1container").attr('gameSecondsRemaining') && 
                data['gameSecondsRemaining'] >= parseFloat($("#game1container").attr('gameSecondsRemaining'))){
                return
            };

            // else:
            // process data
            $("#game1container").find('.score').html(data['team1']) // or idk
            // etc

            // store time associated with loaded data
            $("#game1container").attr('gameSecondsRemaining', data['gameSecondsRemaining']);
        }
        data = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Might be better using `$("#game1container").data('gameSecondsRemaining')` as that's what it's for.